# How to get remote JSON to work with Kendo grid in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, json, kendo-ui

I can successfully make the AJAX call to my service with the following code:

```
var serverData = { "ZoneParent": "123" };

        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/./Services/Reports.svc/getZones",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            jsonp: null,
            jsonpCallback: null,
            data: JSON.stringify(serverData)
        });


        request.done(function (msg) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
        });

        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        });
```

However, when I try to implement the same call with my Kendo grid I get an error

> The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'

for getZones. My service call work fine with DataTables, but I want to switch to Kendo potentially. I have messed with this for days to no avail. The application is not MVC. Here is my Kendo code snippet:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({

        transport: {

            read: {

                url: "/./Services/Reports.svc/getZones",

                dataType: "JSON",

                data: { zoneParent: "123" },

                    type: "POST"
            },

            parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                    return kendo.stringify(data);
                }
        },

            schema: {

                data: "d"
            }
    });

    var grid = $("#allGrids").kendoGrid({

        dataSource: dataSource,

        height: 200
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As **cfeduke** made similar suggestion you can try to add contentType to the read object of the transport read config just as you did in the **$.ajax** call.

e.g.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({

    transport: {

        read: {

            url: "/./Services/Reports.svc/getZones",

            dataType: "json",

            contentType: "application/json",

            data: { zoneParent: "123" },

                type: "POST"
        },

        parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                return kendo.stringify(data);
            }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for the interpretation of the answer @cfeduke gave. Simply adding contentType: "application/json" did the trick. Thanks to cfeduke as well.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the server's reply "Content-type" header is something other than the expected "application/json".

You can use [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html):

```
curl -v -H "Content-type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" \
http://localhost/Services/Reports.svc/getZones
```

to invoke the endpoint and check the returned header values (-v is verbose, you won't see the headers without it).

Sometimes just setting an "Accept: application/json" header is enough to reveal the problem - either the server coerces the output into JSON or it throws an error that can be tracked down.

Answer (score 0):

I am investigating if there is a another way around this. But seems like Kendo has many limitations and this is one of them. Datables doesn't need a header, just the JSON format.

This is what you need to add to your controller that is sending the data (in case its ajax call)

> header("Content-type: application/json");

I wish it wouldn't be like this but Kendo forces this I believe. I prefer datatables, much more freedom and you can customize more.